# Eclipse does not recognize org.jdesktop.*

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jdesktop

I use `JRE system Library [jre7]` and when I `import org.jdesktop.application.Action` I get

```
The import org.jdesktop cannot be resolved
```

I removed the build path by `Build Path > remove from build path` and then  I did
`project > properties > java build path > add Library  > JRE system Library` and still same error .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `org.jdesktop` code is not part of Java SE, so the classes won't be in the JRE.  You need to locate and download a JAR file containing the classes, and then add it to your Eclipse buildpath.

(One place to download the JAR is [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jdesktop/appframework/1.0.3/appframework-1.0.3.jar) ... but it is easy to do your own searching if this link breaks.  Go to Maven Central or findjar.)

Answer (score 35):

If anyone is interested, I had to download 3 JARs:

- **appframework-1.0.3.jar**  (link in previous post) wich contains `org.jdesktop.application` classes,
- **swing-layout-1.0.3.jar** [link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/swinglabs/swing-layout/1.0.3/swing-layout-1.0.3.jar) wich contains `org.jdesktop.layout` classes,
- **swing-worker-1.1.jar** [link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jdesktop/swing-worker/1.1/swing-worker-1.1.jar) wich contains `org.jdesktop.swingworker` classes, required by the others jar

Comment: It's 2020 and this helped a lot with an old project of mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just download the corresponding jar file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbsaf19jar.htm) . And you are good to go. 
Add the jar to your build path.