# Cannot run .JAR file in Windows 10 x64

Tags: java, swing

@ https://odetoolkit.hmc.edu/download.html

This is an elegant JAVA application that can solve simultaneous ODE equations (an opensource alternative to Polymath)

This application (under LINUX) I ran under JRE V1.8xx **after** disabling swing properties. If swing properties were enabled it didn't run! I approached the issue after reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/21886/how-can-i-get-a-java-apps-to-use-the-gtk-theme

At present under Windows.10 X64 I am using JRE 1.9xx ...when I try to launch via

```
java -jar -Xmx512m ODEToolkit.jar
```

it didn't run & gave following error ...Also tried but no success

```
java -jar -Dswing.metalTheme=metal -Xmx512m ODEToolkit.jar

Running from: ./
windows 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/layout/GroupLayout$Group
        at ui.TabbedOutputPanel.<init>(TabbedOutputPanel.java:113)
        at ui.outputpanels.GraphicsRep.<init>(GraphicsRep.java:75)
        at ui.outputpanels.ODEWorkspace.<init>(ODEWorkspace.java:82)
        at ui.GUI.addWorkspace(GUI.java:179)
        at ui.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:111)
        at launch.ODEToolkit.main(ODEToolkit.java:57)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout$Group
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

JDesktop is not part of the Java SE, you have to download and add the jar file yourself

see another post [Eclipse does not recognize org.jdesktop.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882118/eclipse-does-not-recognize-org-jdesktop),  where the jdesktop jar can be downloaded from the [maven repo](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jdesktop/appframework/1.0.3/appframework-1.0.3.jar). (according to the post you will have to download a few more jar files

Then you could run the application as

```
java -Xmx512m -cp ODEToolkit.jar;appframework-1.0.3.jar;(other jar files) launch.ODEToolkit
```

Comment: Hey sir thanks for helping ...I have tried running application `java -cp ODEToolkit.jar;appframework-1.0.3.jar;swing-layout-1.0.3.jar;swing-worker-1.1.jar launch.ODEToolkit` & guess what the GUI did open & ran perfectly. But when I try loading up some official example files ...at the lower right corner it keeps on saying Loading Workspace... I am not a programmer but a field engineer so I have zipped the required .JARs, .BAT & examples. Please try & run them yourself  https://www.mediafire.com/file/cph3chunyjvvghc/ODEToolkit.zip

Comment: @nightcrawler that is already outside scope if the original question (and I won't run someone else's bat file). That cold be a question for a user forum or to the authors..

Comment: I ended up installing multiple JREs solution via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows